# Exception safety moving object off stack

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a mutex protected stack with the following function for popping a value off the top with possible failure:

```
bool try_pop(T& value)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (ctr_.empty())
        return false;
    value = std::move(ctr_.back());
    ctr_.pop_back();
    return true;
}
```

I'm using a `std::vector` as the underlying container. To store a non-copyable T in the stack (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) I have used `std::move` to take the T off the back of the vector, otherwise a copy is made. Two questions: a) Is this correct? Will the T be moved or copied? b) I'm concerned about exception safety. If the move throws, then the stack will not be popped, but the top value may be in a half-moved state. Is this possible and how do I solve?

Comment: Is there a reason you built your stack around `std::vector` instead of around, well, `std::stack`?

Comment: I think a move throwing and leaving the object being moved in a half-state is not a valid implementation of move.

Comment: @Joachim. Because std::stack won't use move semantics?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg. Exactly as CashCow says, std::stack only has a copying push member.

Comment: ok I see there is move_if_noexcept which is a guarantee no-throw.

Comment: @jarmond: A full implementation of C++11 of std::stack should have a moving push as well.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/push

Comment: @Dave. Good to know. MSDN is out-of-date then (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kae5d7cc.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a) It will be moved, assuming it has a move constructor.  For types that have defined a copy constructor but not a move constructor, it will be copied.

b) If you need the strong exception guarantee, then you should use `std::move_if_noexcept` which only enables moving when the input provides a `noexcept()` move constructor.  That way, if the move constructor can throw, it will resort to making a copy so if an exception is thrown the object is left unchanged on the stack.  `std::move_if_noexcept` was explicitly provided to help provide the strong guarantee in cases like this.

Edit:  As Howard Hinnant points out, the current code example is using move assignment, not move construction, so `std::move_if_noexcept` will not likely do what you want.  To solve it while using assignment, you'll need to write your own wrapper which is based on the `std::move_if_noexcept`:

```
template <class T> typename std::conditional<
!std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value && std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value,
const T&, T&&>::type move_if_assign_noexcept(T& x) noexcept {
   return std::move(x);
}
```

Comment: Move assignment, not move construction is used.  Thus for strong exception safety `is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value` must be true, not `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value`.  `std::move_if_noexcept` tests construction, not assignment.  So jarmond really needs to build a variant that tests `is_nothrow_move_assignable`.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct (apart from the whole exception-safety thing) and it will be moved (if it supports moving).

As you have discovered, it's impossible to offer the strong exception guarantee if moves can throw- you have to resort to copying in that case. However, throwing moves are a very rare thing, so I wouldn't think about them too much.

Answer (score 2):

1) Will be moved, since `unique_ptr` has move c-tor.

2)

From n3337 20.7.1.2

```
unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& u) noexcept;
unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr&& u) noexcept;
```